# How to remove ""[], from list

Tags: android, list, arraylist, spinner, android-studio-3.0

I have

> ["A","B","C","D"]

I want to bind this to the android spinner. How can I remove   []"", from  `["A","B","C","D"]` so only characters will display in the spinner.

```
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String asd = "";
            arrayList3.clear();
            asd= arrayList2.get(position);
            String[] items = asd.split(",");
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(items);
            for(String item : list)
             {
                arrayList3.add(item);
             }
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList3);
            sp2.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: ["A","B","C","D"] what type of data is this?

Comment: ArrayList<String> arrayList3 = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: String[] items = asd.split(",");....what is *asd* here?

Comment: Is json data ,I thing you got it  from server.

Comment: yes , but from asset .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace this code with foreach loop in your code

```
   for(String item : list)
    {
        item = item.replace("[","");
        item = item.replace("]","");
        item = item.replace("\"","");

        arrayList3.add(item);
    }
```